# Login automatically using python

Tags: python, html, authentication

So I've seen that there are a couple of similar questions but none of them worked for me. This is the login page that I'm trying to log in to:

https://cas.lu.se/cas/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ceq.lth.se%2Frapporter%2F%3Flasar_lp%3Dalla%26program%3Dsamtliga%26kurskod%3DEDAA45%26sort%3Dkurskod

The form has the following html:

```
<div class="box fl-panel" id="login">
                    <form action="/cas/login;jsessionid=C32FA3678B0093A4DB474BFD56858B6C?service=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ceq.lth.se%2Frapporter%2F%3Flasar_lp%3Dalla%26program%3Dsamtliga%26kurskod%3DEDAA45%26sort%3Dkurskod" class="fm-v clearfix" id="fm1" method="post">

              Please enter your userid without "@lu.se" at the end.<br/><br/>
                        <div class="row fl-controls-left">
                            <label class="fl-label" for="username"><span class="accesskey">U</span>sername:</label>
                            <input accesskey="u" autocomplete="false" class="required" id="username" name="username" onblur="makeLowercase();" size="25" tabindex="1" type="text" value=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row fl-controls-left">
                            <label class="fl-label" for="password"><span class="accesskey">P</span>assword:</label>
                            <input accesskey="p" autocomplete="off" class="required" id="password" name="password" size="25" tabindex="2" type="password" value=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row btn-row">
                            <input name="lt" type="hidden" value="LT-61720-irxrtm4JCzVNIJ2pkpidljNGOw5KYX"/>
                            <input name="execution" type="hidden" value="e1s1"/>
                            <input name="_eventId" type="hidden" value="submit"/>
                            <input accesskey="l" class="btn-submit" name="submit" tabindex="4" type="submit" value="LOGIN"/>
                            <input accesskey="c" class="btn-reset" name="reset" tabindex="5" type="reset" value="CLEAR"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

So far I've tried using urllib in the following way:

```py
from urllib import request, parse
auth = parse.urlencode({"username": "??",
                                "password": "??",
                                "lt": "LT-61720-irxrtm4JCzVNIJ2pkpidljNGOw5KYX",
                                "execution": "e1s1",
                                "_eventId": "submit",
                                "submit": "LOGIN", })
auth = auth.encode("ascii")
req = request.Request(url, 
with request.urlopen(url) as f:
    res = f.read()
```

The problem is that the only thing I get back is the html for the original page itself, and not the page that it is supposed to load after authentication. I'm also not sure what the action attribute contains in the form tag...

Comment: How to debug it without login and password?

Comment: @Alderven I'm not sure what you're asking. I do have a password and username. I'm trying to automize the process.